# Why does reference = null not affect the referenced object?

Tags: javascript, types, reference, null

I know this works, but I don't know why or the reasoning behind why it was made to work this way:

```
var foo = [5, 10];
var bar = foo;
console.log(foo); //[5, 10]
console.log(bar); //[5, 10]
bar[0] = 1; 
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]
bar = null;
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]
```

I would have expected not just `bar` to become null, but `foo` as well. I'd love some help understanding this.

Comment: Why would you have expected that?

Comment: Because `bar` is a reference (a "pointer") to the object, and not the actual object itself.

Comment: But like I demonstrated, pointers to the properties of the objects affect the values themselves, which is where my confusion enters.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: you should look at the difference between [rebinding and mutating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) operations. `bar[0] = 1` is mutating; it affects the object that `bar` points to. `bar = None` is rebinding; it just affects what the identifier `bar` means.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Why don't you put that in an answer? It answers the first part of my question, thanks!

Comment: @Bloodyaugust check it out: `var foo = {bar:"bar"}; var barVal = foo.bar; barVal = "Hello"; console.log(foo.bar === barVal);`.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust just did! But what do you mean about the first part of your question? What's the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between [rebinding and mutating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding#Rebinding_and_mutation) operations.

```
bar[0] = 1
```

is mutating; it affects the object that `bar` points to.

```
bar = null
```

is rebinding; it just affects what the identifier `bar` means.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for! But what is the reasoning for the language to work this way? It made sense to me that mutations and rebindings were the same thing.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: If the language didn't work this way (if there were no rebinding operations), imagine how a `for` loop over a list would work. Every iteration of the for loop might have a line like `x = lst[i]`, which would change what the variable `x` contained, and therefore every previous variable that was ever assigned to `x`!

Comment: Because without references (binding), you would have to pass the entire array around, and not just a pointer to it.

Comment: Also, why would bar = null be considered a rebinding as opposed to a mutation?

Comment: `bar = null` is a rebinding.  More specifically, an "unbinding."

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: For the reason I describe above in my comment about `for` loops. Sometimes people want to say `var thisvar = list[i]`. If this were a mutation, it would be affecting everything that `thisvar` had ever been!

Comment: It makes a lot more sense when you think of variables as names or labels.  When you do a "mutation" you're changing the thing itself.  When you do a "rebinding" you're just moving the label to something else

Answer (score 3):

When you  do `bar = null;` that just assigns something to the value of the `bar` variable.  It does not affect what used to be assigned to `bar`.  That object continues to live on and if there are other references to it, it stays alive with its value untouched.

When you do this:

```
var foo = [5, 10];
var bar = foo;
```

You have three entities.  You have an array `[5,10]` and two variables each with a reference to that array.  If you change the array, then since both variables point to the same array, you will see that change no matter which variable you reference the array through.

But, if you set `bar = null`, that just affects the `bar` variable which then no longer has a reference to the array.  It doesn't affect the array at all which is still pointed to by `foo`.

In fact, if you did this:

```
var foo = [5, 10];
var bar = foo;
bar = [20,30];
```

You'd have the same sort of result.  After the second line of code both `bar` and `foo` pointed to the same array, but after the third line, `bar` now points to a new array and only `foo` points to the original array.  The key is realizing that there's a difference between using `bar` to modify the object it points to as in `bar[0] = 1` versus reassigning the whole value of bar as in `bar = [20,30]`.  In the first case, the underlying object that both `foo` and `bar` point to is changed.  In the second case, the underlying object that `bar` originally pointed to is not touched.  Instead, `bar` is changed to point a new object and the prior object is not touched.

Answer (score 0):

You have two pointers to the array. Bar = foo copies the original pointer.  Dereferencing bar does not dereference foo.

Read more @ 
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var foo = [5, 10];
```

It creates a reference to an array, like this

```
foo --->  [5, 10]
```

When you assign `bar` to `foo`, you now have

```
foo --->  [5, 10]

bar ------^
```

When you call

```
bar[0] = 1;
```

you get

```
foo --->  [1, 10]

bar ------^
```

where `foo` and `bar` point to the same object.

When you call

```
bar = null;
```

you now have

```
foo --->  [1, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference, but it's definition is just a pointer to some object. When you assign `null` to bar, you simply delete this "pointer" that was stored in `bar`, making it no longer point to object.

Imagine this as an address, written on sheets of paper. If sheet `foo` and `bar` have same address on it and you issue a command: go to address written on sheet `foo` and put something in house there, after operation is done, naturally, whoever looks at any of those sheets and checks out that address, will find those changes. Now your assignment of `null` is just same as wiping this address from sheet with eraser. It doesn't touch neither any other sheets, nor house in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of variables as labels.  Makes explaining them easier.

```
//Create an array containing 5 and 10, and put the label "foo" on it
var foo = [5, 10];
//Put the label "bar" on the thing with the label "foo"
var bar = foo;      
console.log(foo); //[5, 10]
console.log(bar); //[5, 10]
//Take the thing labeled "bar" (which also has the label "foo") and change the first element to 1
bar[0] = 1;         
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]
//Take the label "bar" and attach it to nothing
bar = null;
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]
```

var foo = [5, 10];
var bar = foo;
console.log(foo); //[5, 10]
console.log(bar); //[5, 10]
bar[0] = 1; 
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]
bar = null;
console.log(foo); //[1, 10]